Mocking sheet in junit is giving invalid use of matchers exception
I'm trying to mock the below method.
Actual method:
public List<PricingSchemesDTO> loadPricingSchemeDto(
    Sheet pricingSchemeSheet, List<String> errors) {}

Inside junit,
when(readAndProcessPricingSchemeUtils.loadPricingSchemeDto(
        Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
    .thenReturn(pricingSchemesDTOList);

But this above line is giving the below exception - org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException.
Can someone help to mock this correctly?

That looks okay. Can you show the whole test? Are you using matchers elsewhere, such as for return values or parameters to actual calls? Do you ever mix matchers with actual values? Also, there should be more output from Mockito than just the exception. Look at your console, it often tells you in detail what is wrong.

Where and how do you initialize readAndProcessPricingSchemeUtils? Is it a Mockito mock or spy?

I tried both using mock and spy.  In both cases, the actual method is getting called and the result is empty. loadPricingSchemeDto - this public method is not mocked and actually getting executed.

I think you'll need to post more of your test for us to be able to help. The call in your question looks fine, but Matchers work via side-effects and some other test might be polluting your test state.

@Vasavi that does not really clarify my question. Make sure to include a [mre] with the annotated test class, its annotated fields, the setup method (@BeforeEach), and the complete test method itself.
